# I Want to know how to change the style of an partcular <li> in a particular <ul> by javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to know how to change the style of an particular `<li>` in a particular `<ul>` by JavaScript

My code goes something like this

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="number1"><a href="#1">1</a></li>
  <li id="number2"><a href="#2">2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now let's say I want to change the background color of the `li#number1` of the `ul#menu` using JavaScript.

Comment: When do you want to change the styles, on click, hover, ...?

Comment: why don't you use jquery? Jquery can handle these sort of problems very easily.

Comment: well i want to change styles on click

Comment: look for quick jQuery tutorials.

Comment: and i just need a way like something that goes like document.getElementById("number1").style.backgroundColor = "blue";

Comment: can anyone write me a sample code

Comment: it should work when i click on a normal button

Comment: If your question is about how to do something when something is clicked, as your comment above seems to indicate, please add that information to the question yourself. Also, please clarify if you want to change the color when the element itself is clicked, or when a button is clicked.

Comment: There is only one `#number1` element in the entire document, so it is meaningless to specify that is the one inside the `ul#menu`.

Answer (score 3):

This is your solution in plain JavaScript:

```
var el = document.querySelector('#number1');
el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
});
```

Comment: To be a bit picky, setting styles directly on elements is not really best practices; it may be an after-effect of the jQuery-style programming with `$.css` etc. It would be preferable to set a class on the element.

Comment: To be ridiculously picky, you can provide HTML4 backwards compatibility using `getElementById` and you can make the click function more efficient by using `this` instead of `el` to avoid closures.

Comment: Sure, you can be picky about these things. Refactoring is up to the OP, of course, and I agree about adding classes instead of CSS directly. I just used that because the OP referenced the `.style` syntax in a comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using javascript and button.

```
<script>
function doSth(){
    var nodes = document.getElementById("menu").getElementsByTagName("li");
    for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].id == 'number2') {
             nodes[i].style.background = "blue";
         }
    }
}

</script>
<ul id="menu">
<li id="number1"><a href="#1">1</a></li>
<li id="number2"><a href="#2">2</a></li></ul>
<input type="button" onClick="doSth();" value="Click here"/>
```

Comment: Why would you iterate over DOM notes to find one with a particular ID, when you could jump directly to it with `getElementById`?

Comment: Its because the asker wants. Please read his question carefully. He wants to select li with id ='number1' of the ul with id ='menu'.

Comment: It's still redundant, it doesn't matter where it's located, it should still be the only element with that ID

Comment: Yes i know there can be only one id in a document, so selecting id will do the work. But the asker wants the way i answered according to the question.

Comment: Why recommend an inefficient solution to the OP instead of providing a better solution that doesn't perfectly fit the criteria but still does what they want? You shouldn't assume OP knows they're asking for an inefficient solution.

Comment: what if number1 is a class? You can suggest the OP about efficient solution but degrading the correct solution to the question is really not good.

Comment: Whatever the selector desired--an ID or a class--you never need to iterate over elements to find one which matches the selector. That's what `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` do for a living. In this case, `querySelector('ul#menu li#number1')` will do this job. Actually, in the comments on the question the OP already gave the correct solution for changing the style itself, and there's no need to rewrite that. It appears he's stuck on how to wire up that logic to a button click.